# Why is this definite integral infinite?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm finding the definite integral $$\int_0^1-\frac1x\,dx$$
I put this into my graphics calculator and the answer came back as $-\infty$

But doing it by hand, I get $0$. My workings:
Find antiderivative of $-\frac1x$: well this equals $0$.
Apply boundaries to this: Well....this simply gives $0$ again, as there is no variable in the antiderivative...

How did the calculator get $\infty$?

Comment: The antiderivative of $-\frac1x$ is $-\ln x$ when $x>0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott to be picky, it should be $-\ln |x|$.

Comment: @Vim: In general, yes; here, though, we know that $x>0$. I probably should have made that explicit, so I’ve modified the previous comment.

Comment: Why did you think the antiderivative of $-\frac1x$ was $0$ ? Clearly the derivative of $0$ is $0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I'm guessing the OP has tried to apply the rule for the integration of polynomials to $-1/x$. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Mattos well, the funny fact is that "$\frac10x^0$" does not look like $0$ at all.

Answer (score 3):

The anti derivative of $-1/x$ is simply $-\log x$ (base $e$ logarithm), since
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log x = \frac{1}{x}.
$$

So
$$
\int_0^1 -\frac{1}{x} \, dx = [-\log x]^1_0 = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \log x = -\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $-\frac{1}{x}$. Notice that there is asymptotic behavior at $x = 0$, so
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 -\frac{1}{x}\,dx &=\lim_{k\to 0^+} -\int_k^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
&=\lim_{k\to0^+} -\log x \big|_k^1\\
&=-\log 1 +\lim_{k\to 0^+}\log k \\
&=\lim_{k\to 0^+}\log k \\
&=-\infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The "integration rule" $\int x^n dx= \frac{1}{n+ 1}x^{n+ 1}$  does not apply when n= -1 because $\frac{1}{-1+ 1}$ because $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, not equal to 0 as you seem to think.